# JavaScript Calculator Does not respond

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

[console img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTotp.png)

```js
const num1Element = document.querySelector("#num1");
const num2Element = document.querySelector("#num2");
const resultElement = document.querySelector("#result");
const operatorlememt = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operation]")

function summary() {
  if (operatorElememt == "+") {
    const sumElement = Number(num1.value) + Number(num2.value);
    resultElement.innerHTML = sumElement;
  }
}

function multi() {
  if (operatorElememt == "*") {
    const multiElement = Number(num1.value) * Number(num2.value);
    resultElement.innerHTML = multiElement;
  }
}

function divide() {
  if (operatorElememt == "/") {
    const divideElement = Number(num1.value) / Number(num2.value);
    resultElement.innerHTML = divideElement;
  }
}

function subtraction() {
  if (operatorElememt == "-") {
    const subtractionElement = Number(num1.value) - Number(num2.value);
    resultElement.innerHTML = subtractionElement;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<input class="num1" type="text">
<select name="" id="operator" class="operator">
  <option data-operation value="-">-</option>
  <option data-operation value="+">+</option>
  <option data-operation value="/">/</option>
  <option data-operation value="*">*</option>
</select>
<input class="num2" type="text">
<button onclick="summary();divide();multi();subtraction()">Click</button>
<br>
<span class="result_con">
        <label for=""  id="result"></label>
    </span>
```

Console doesn't give any error code or any other result and I am quite new in to the subject. I was expecting a result regarding the selected operation. To select the operation I wrote select section and added the operations. I inteed to keep  select part. Thanks in advance

Comment: The console is definitely showing you an error. You may want to check your console settings.

Comment: I added the image. Settings are default for now.

Comment: Simple typo. variable name is wrong for the first error. Second error is `querySelectorAll` an html collection is not going to equal a string.

Comment: @Berkan - thanks for adding the console image. An error may only show in the console after you type in your values and click your "Click" button since your logic runs in the onclick event.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort it helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you are a beginner. There were quiet a few issues with your code. I am attaching the snippet of the changes I made (I wouldn't consider myself an expert either and still may have overlooked something)

```
<body>

    <div class="container"></div>
    <input id="num1" type="text">
    <select name="" id="operator" class="operator">
        <option data-operation value="-">-</option>
        <option data-operation value="+">+</option>
        <option data-operation value="/">/</option>
        <option data-operation value="*">*</option>
    </select>
    <input id="num2" type="text">
    <button onclick="summary();divide();multi();subtraction()">Click</button>
    <br>
    <span class="result_con">
        <label for=""  id="result"></label>
    </span>


    <script>

        const num1Element = document.querySelector("#num1");
        const num2Element = document.querySelector("#num2");
        const resultElement = document.querySelector("#result");
        const operatorElememt = document.querySelector("#operator")

        function summary() {
            if (operatorElememt.value == "+") {
                console.log("Adding");
                const sumElement = Number(num1Element.value) + Number(num2Element.value);
                resultElement.innerHTML = sumElement;
            }
        }

        function multi() {
            if (operatorElememt.value == "*") {
            const multiElement = Number(num1Element.value) * Number(num2Element.value);
            resultElement.innerHTML = multiElement;
            }
        }

        function divide() {
            if (operatorElememt.value == "/") {
            const divideElement = Number(num1Element.value) / Number(num2Element.value);
            resultElement.innerHTML = divideElement;
            }
        }

        function subtraction() {
            if (operatorElememt.value == "-") {
            const subtractionElement = Number(num1Element.value) - Number(num2Element.value);
            resultElement.innerHTML = subtractionElement;
            }
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Here are the issues I found:

1. You are trying to access your input element using a CSS selector for ids but you did not give those elements an id attribute
2. The select element works like an input element except it has a dropdown and limited options. You just need to get the select element like you would get an input Element. This also includes calling operatorElement.value
3. You are missing an E when getting the select element :)

And I would suggest instead of different functions, nest your conditions inside one event handler

Comment: I would add that querySelector() with #id is significantly slower than a getElementById() - https://jsbench.me/7clbl0gb8j/1

Comment: I felt like a noob and I am a noob for sure but sometimes it is hard to admit :'').  Thank you it helped a lot.